# Purpose of Simultaneous Diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the purpose of doing simultaneous diagonalization?? What problem can be solved with this concept??

Comment: A couple of applications come to mind: simultaneous diagonalisation allows to define the root space decomposition in a semi-simple Lie algebra. While not completely the same as simultaneous diagonalisation of endomorphisms, the spectral theorem in finite dimension says that any quadratic form shares a common orthogonal basis with a definite positive quadratic form. Furthermore, it can be a tool in proving certain results, such as the fact that any definite positive endomorphism of a finite dimensional euclidean space admits a unique definite positive square root.

Answer (score 4):

It gives you a basis of vectors that are eigenvectors of both operators. Such simultaneous eigenvectors have special significance in quantum mechanics, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Simultaneous diagonalization also is a sufficent condition to check that two matrices commute. (Although diagonalization is usually much harder than just multiplying them to check)